# How can I arrange values stored in few columns to be stored under one column only

Tags: r, list

I have a list with few columns that I would like to transform it to one column where each value of the columns will be stored in one column only, each below other.How can I do that?
For example:

```
test1 <- list( c(a='a',b='b',c='c'), c(a='Moshe',b='Yossi',c='Ram'))
 test1
[[1]]
  a   b   c 
"a" "b" "c" 

[[2]]
      a       b       c 
"Moshe" "Yossi"   "Ram"
```

The output that I need ( as a list or a data frame):

```
a
Moshe
Yossi
Ram
```

Comment: Do you need only single output (a Moshe Yossi Ram)

Comment: Perhaps you want `lapply(test1, stack)`

Comment: Is this what you want?   test2 <- data.frame(col1 = paste(test1[[1]],test1[[2]], sep = " "))
> test2
     col1
1 a Moshe
2 b Yossi
3   c Ram

Comment: Yes, a single output, a as a column name and the names as values

Comment: Please show a full desired output. Your description is very confusing

Comment: So what about all the rest of `b` and `c`? I don't understand the logic behind this

Comment: I don't need those columns.I got a table from outsource that I would like to change as I've described.All columns store the same type of values : names in this case.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Use paste function for the same

```
paste(test1[[1]][1],test1[[2]],collapse="")
[1] "a Moshea Yossia Ram"
```

Here's your output as you said

```
test1 <- data.frame(c(a='Moshe',b='Yossi',c='Ram'), stringsAsFactors = F)

names(test1) <- "a"

print(test1)

      a
a Moshe
b Yossi
c   Ram
```

Or a bit more problematically

```
setNames(data.frame(test1[[2]]), test1[[1]][1])
```

Comment: Hello @Arun kumar mahesh, I need  a single output, "a" as a column name and the names:Moshea Yossia Ram as values

Comment: You did everything by hand. I don't this is what they looking for. You could achieve this by `setNames(data.frame(test1[[2]]),  test1[[1]][1])` for instance.

Comment: @mql4beginner Is the the output are looking for

Comment: @mql4beginner I don't understand, you wanted to know how to manually write this without any code?

Comment: @David Arenburg, No,  your comment is the right way , can you post it as an answer?

Comment: @mql4beginner is that what you expect am i wrong in my code

Comment: @Arun kumar mahesh, your code is good, thanks, but it takes manual coding  like stating the values.

Comment: @mql4beginner ok thanks, got a down vote so that's why need to know

Comment: Thank you @Arun kumar mahesh. That wasn't me..

Comment: @mql4beginner when you use dataframes you should use manual coding, David shown the code when we use lists

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @DavidArenburg your code works fine when we use lists rather than dataframes

Comment: @Arunkumarmahesh OP has a list, don't you get it? Your code just manually creating a `data.frame`. That is not useful in any way.

Comment: @Arunkumarmahesh Your code does not scale at all. Your solution does not work (is not practical rather) if there are hundreds of names.

Answer (score 1):

How about using `reshape2::melt`?

```
df <- reshape2::melt(test1[[2]])
colnames(df) <- "a"
df
```